# Setting ACL Folder Permissions - Deny to System

Tags: powershell, acl

I've taken some working code i had in a previous script which alters the security permissions of folders using POSH, although, instead of allowing modify perms to an account, i now want to DENY, SYSTEM from accessing this folder. ({this is to turn off the horrible Windows10UpgraderApp.exe} from running during an MDT Task Sequence).

Here's my code that i thought would work:

```
New-Item -ItemType directory -Path C:\Windows10upgrade -force

$privuser = "system"
$Acl1 = Get-Acl "C:\Windows10Upgrade"
$Ar1 = New-Object system.security.accesscontrol.filesystemaccessrule("$privuser","deny")
$Acl1.SetAccessRule($Ar1)
```

This is the error i'm getting:

```
New-Object : Cannot find an overload for "FileSystemAccessRule" and the argument count: "2".
At line:3 char:8
+ $Ar1 = New-Object system.security.accesscontrol.filesystemaccessrule("$privuser" ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [New-Object], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConstructorInvokedThrowException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand
```

Bit lost on this one - this code works in a previously used script.

Thanks in advance

EDIT: After receiving the below advice (thanks) I now run this code:

```
New-Item -type directory -path C:\Windows10Upgrade -force
$Acl = Get-Acl "C:\Windows10Upgrade"
$Ar = New-Object  system.security.accesscontrol.filesystemaccessrule("System","FullControl","Deny")
$Acl.SetAccessRule($Ar)
Set-Acl "C:\Windows10Upgrade" $Acl
```

I know it can be deceptive as the Special permissions box is ticked when you make changes this way but, this doesn't throw an error, but the permissions look the same for system, like it has unfortunately NOT successfully applied the change to the Access Rule.

2nd EDIT: Something seems to have taken place, but now there are multiple permission entries for SYSTEM, the desired ACL rule is at the top for SYSTEM, yet, full control is still assigned below:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> get-acl -Path C:\Windows10upgrade | select *


PSPath                  : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\Windows10upgrade
PSParentPath            : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\
PSChildName             : Windows10upgrade
PSDrive                 : C
PSProvider              : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem
CentralAccessPolicyId   : 
CentralAccessPolicyName : 
AccessToString          : NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM Deny  FullControl
                          BUILTIN\Administrators Allow  FullControl
                          BUILTIN\Administrators Allow  268435456
                          NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM Allow  FullControl
                          NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM Allow  268435456
                          BUILTIN\Users Allow  ReadAndExecute, Synchronize
                          NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users Allow  Modify, Synchronize
                          NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users Allow  -536805376
AuditToString           : 
Path                    : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\Windows10upgrade
Owner                   : BUILTIN\Administrators
Group                   : COMPANY\Roles - Technical Services
Access                  : {System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule, System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule, 
                          System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule, System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule...}
Sddl                    : O:BAG:S-1-5-21-2593231249-3506496172-1181922232-40387D:AI(D;;FA;;;SY)(A;ID;FA;;;BA)(A;OICIIOID;GA;;;BA)(A;ID;FA;;;SY)(A;OI
                          CIIOID;GA;;;SY)(A;OICIID;0x1200a9;;;BU)(A;ID;0x1301bf;;;AU)(A;OICIIOID;SDGXGWGR;;;AU)
AccessRightType         : System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights
AccessRuleType          : System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule
AuditRuleType           : System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAuditRule
AreAccessRulesProtected : False
AreAuditRulesProtected  : False
AreAccessRulesCanonical : True
AreAuditRulesCanonical  : True
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is in the error message. Referencing [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.accesscontrol.filesystemaccessrule(v=vs.110).aspx), a minimum of 3 arguments is required. That's for [this constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tafsxecs(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
public FileSystemAccessRule(
    string identity,
    FileSystemRights fileSystemRights,
    AccessControlType type
)
```

It looks like you're missing the middle argument, [`FileSystemRights`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.accesscontrol.filesystemrights(v=vs.110).aspx) as you've specified the user as "system" and `AccessControlType` to be deny... but not which permissions to deny.

---

**Edit**

Right click on the folder, and go to `Properties` > `Security` > `Advanced`. You should see a screen similar to the below.

[image: Security settings after running script for System and Admin]

Blue highlighted row is the one added by the script. Yellow highlighted row is inherited, so it's not set on the folder but on the whole drive. For me, this is why there were multiple permission lines.

This isn't really an issue as `Deny` trumps `Allow`. To confirm, you can set `Deny` permissions to your user or the Admin group as above and try to access the folder.

If the permission is not inherited, but is instead applied to the folder, you will need to make use of the `RemoveAccessRule` method in a similar way to how `SetAccessRule` is used:

```
$remove = New-Object  system.security.accesscontrol.filesystemaccessrule("System","FullControl","Allow")
$Acl.RemoveAccessRule($remove)
```

Comment: Thanks for this, edit above - not seemingly applying the change, do i need a domain prefix for system, even though it's a local account?

Comment: I think the issue is calling on the system account to apply changes to the ACL on. I said that like Yoda but - can anyone help on this with Modifying system permissions to a folder?

Comment: @Royston Please see edit, based on some analysis on Windows 7.

Comment: Thanks for this. It did appear to work. Yet, the program seems to still write to the folder anyway and create essentially a malware style upgrade screen . Bummer. Your answer is technically correct though. I’ll investigate this next week, fun stuff! Thanks again.